# Finding a limit of a sequence by looking at it as if it were a limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Today, I was doing some math, and I found an assignment, finding a limit of a sequence, $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, $n \in \aleph$. I was wondering, is it possible to find the limit of a function, $\lim_{x \to \infty}$, $x \in \Re$. If the limit of a function exists for reals, then the case of natural numbers is covered. Are those limits the same? When can one conclude that they are the same, and, for instance, use L'Hospitals rule, or MacLaurin's series expansion?

And few more things, can one use L'Hospitals rule for sequences, when  $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, $n \in \aleph$? Can you actually derive a sequence? If you can, when you can do that? I could not find answers to these questions. 
Can you use MacLaurin's series expansion when $\lim_{x \to \infty}$?

Thank you for your time. Cheers!

Comment: As a side note \mathbb is used for the sets you are asking, for instance \mathbb{R} or \mathbb{N} for the real and natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a given function and suppose that 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L.
$$
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L$. This is clear since given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M$ (which we can choose to be an integer) such that if $x>M$ then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. In particular $n>M\implies |f(n)-L|<\varepsilon$.

The converse is not true.

There is an analogue of L'hopital for sequences namely the [stolz-cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your response! 

Thanks for the explanation. I am familiar with the Stolz-Cesaro theorem, but my question was about using l'Hospitals rule, when we look at the sequence as a function. And also, deriving a sequence, once you look at the variable as real, not integer.

Answer (score 1):

As a side-note. You can't use L'Hôpital's Rule to evaluate a sequential limit, that's because a sequence is a function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, hence is not continuous and therefore is not derivable.

Comment: But what if I look at it as f: R -> R, switch the variable with a continuous one, and then derive it? Will the following conclusions be correct?

Comment: Yes, but you have to justify that fact (formally). A lemma you can use is the sequential criterior for continuous functions.

Comment: Thank you! Can you, please, provide more detail with that lemma? English is not my primary language of studies, I just started to learn English terminology.

Comment: Sure, the lema states the following: Let f be a function from a set A to R. Then f is continuous at a point "a" in A if and only if for each sequence (a_n) that converges to "a", we have that the sequence (f(a_n)) converges to f(a).

Comment: Sorry for being a dummy, but please, can you give me a link, or something?

Comment: No problem. Here's a link: [http://mathonline.wikidot.com/sequential-criterion-for-the-continuity-of-a-function]

Answer (score 0):

Take $$f (x)=\sin (x\pi) .$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f (n)=0,$$
but
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f (x) $$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I said if it exists for reals, does it surely exists for natural numbers, not the other way around. Not helpful.